# In MVC 2, how to bind a Html.TextBox to a Model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

My model has a property of "output" and my form has a TextBox named "output", both spelled exactly the same.  When I fill out the form and post it, the returning view has unexpected results.

Specifically, I receive the posted "output" form variable which is then bound to my Model in the Controller Method, then I change this variable to a different value before I pass the Model back to the view.

the posted output property is "one thing"
my Model property is set to "another"

I have this in my code: `<%= Html.TextBox("output") %>`

Which renders to this: `<input id="output" name="output" type="text" value="one thing" />`

However, when debugging, the Model *does* contain the correct value ("another").

Its using the posted value rather than the value assigned in the controller.  Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a strongly typed view like so:

```
<%@ Page ... Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<...TestModel>" %>
```

And having an EditorFor replacing your

`<%= Html.TextBox("output") %>` like so `<%= Html.EditorFor(p=>p.output) %>`

you can do in your Controller

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("output", new ValueProviderResult("Some string", string.Empty, new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700274/mvc-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-textbox-in-a-post)