# Prevent value to be preserved in ModelState

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modelstate, modelstatedictionary

Good day!

ASP.NET MVC makes a good job by storing values of inputs during GET/POST cycle inside `ModelState` and automagically putting them into inputs in case of validation errors.

But on my form I have CAPTCHA field which shouldn't be preserved during validation errors (CAPTCHA value is regenerated on each request).

I've tried to achieve this by setting

```
if (TryUpdateModel(model))
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    ModelState.Remove("CaptchaValue"); // ModelState does have CaptchaValue 
    return View(model); // CaptchaValue is empty in model
}
```

But it doesn't work.

May be there is an attribute which I can apply to my model field to prevent it from preserve in ModelState?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this in nearby thread [MVC - How to change the value of a textbox in a post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700274/mvc-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-textbox-in-a-post):

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("CaptchaValue", new ValueProviderResult(String.Empty, String.Empty, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture));
```

But it seems to be a bit ugly.

Comment: You can add a little syntactic sugar to this by making an extension method ModelState.ClearValue(string PropertyName) which would do SetModelValue for you and should make the code a little cleaner.

Comment: But how to make it work with any type of a field (both value types and reference types), not just string?

Comment: Hmmm not so sure, you might have to dig around in modelbinders to try and work out the type then instantiate it via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bind attribute on the action parameter to control model binding behaviour:

```
public ActionResult YourActionName([Bind(Exclude = "CaptchaValue")]ModelType model)
```

Comment: It seems you get me wrong, I need field to be binded (to get access to it in controller), but I don't need to repopulate it in case of form redisplay (when validation errors occured).

Comment: Ah, OK, in which case I guess it will need to be the ugly SetModelValue