# Reset DateTime input box to blank after failing ModelState.IsValid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have an input box in a view which is for a required date

If the user leaves this blank, the `ModelState` returns `false` and the model is returned to the view.

However, in this case, the `DateTime` field is then populated with the value `DateTime.MinValue` (01/01/0001)

How do I clear this value from the model, and return a blank inputbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not validation, then define that date as `nullable` in model

```
DateTime? AnyDate {get; set;}
```

So, issue will solved. When user doesn't enter `AnyDate`, after post it will be `null`. If it will not work, you can write in action:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //control for any case
   if(model.AnyDate == DateTime.MinValue) model.AnyDate = null;      
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - I didn't realize that I could have a nullable property with a [Required] annotation... now if there is nothing entered the value passed to the controller is null and it fails the validation - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once you are POST-ing back to your View, you will need to manipulate the values in your ModelState (not your Model) using the [SetModelValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.setmodelvalue(v=vs.100).aspx) method. Alternatively, you could `Remove()` the offending entry, but that has other implications (i.e., damaging your model in the ModelStateDictionary object).

For example if your data element was called `RequiredDateTime`, then your controller code might be:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ThisAction(int id, YourModel model)
{
    // Process the 'IsValid == true' condition
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // ...
        return RedirectToAction("NextAction");
    }

    // Process the 'IsValid == false' condition
    if (ModelState.ContainsKey("RequiredDateTime"))
    {
        ModelState.SetModelValue("RequiredDateTime", new ValueProviderResult(...));
    }

    // ...

    return View(model);
}
```

**EDIT**

A little additional research turned up the following, see also:

[MVC - How to change the value of a textbox in a post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700274/mvc-how-to-change-the-value-of-a-textbox-in-a-post)

[How to modify posted form data within controller action before sending to view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686652/how-to-modify-posted-form-data-within-controller-action-before-sending-to-view)

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return null value, you must edit the entity of your model to nullable as follow:

```
public Class MyObject
{
    String parameter {get; set;}
    DateTime? time {get; set;}
}
```

And if you want to change the value that the user enter before re-rendering the page with fields, you have to edit the model object to DateTime.MinValue (for instance) as follow :

```
    public ActionResult MyMethod(MyObject model)
    {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        ...
        } 
    else
        {
        model.time = DateTime.MinValue; 
        }
    return View(model);
    }
```